# Can we define multiple orderers and ca in connection.json?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Can we define multiple orderers and ca in connection.json, so that if one orderer is down then client application will automatically connect with the another available orderer? And same with the case of CA server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node sdk for hyperledger fabric v1.0 has always supported adding multiple orderers in it's various pre-releases of v1.0 so the hyperledger composer connection profile has always supported being able to add multiple orderers. However with the release of rc1 the comments to the methods have been updated to say that only the first orderer in the list is used (which implies that for 1.0 the node sdk won't support multiple orderers for the v1.0 release) and as an implication of that hyperledger composer only supports a single orderer in it's connection profile (although multiple ones could be defined).
The connection profile also only supports defining a single CA. Hyperledger Composer doesn't provide any sort of concept of HA for the CA.

Comment: Ok, so can we add a HA proxy between client - orderer and client - CA cluster