# Hyperledger Fabric Composer for Production

Tags: hyperledger-composer

If hyperledger Fabric Composer is production ready does that mean we can use multiple orderers in connection profiles ? Because [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849887/can-we-define-multiple-orderers-and-ca-in-connection-json) (although a year old) it says that we can define but it will use only the first defined orderer. I could not find any other instances to negate whats in the attached link.
Do you guys have any idea ?

What are the limitations of Composer as far as Production setup is concerned ?

Comment: there is already a response to this (relating to orderer configuration question) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51512824/using-kafka-configuration-in-hyperledger-composer-setup

Comment: Thanks @PaulO'Mahony. So that means we still cannot use composer for production because there wii be no consensus mechanism?

Comment: No it doesn't mean that. In a non solo orderer setup you will have a concensus mechanism, and you only need to send to proposals to be ordered to 1 of those orderers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limitation in the fabric-sdk-node for 1.1 which only supports sending to the first orderer in the list. However when composer supports fabrci 1.2 it will use the fabric-sdk-node for 1.2 which will now allow multiple orderers in the list. It will attempt to send to the first orderer but if that fails it will try the next one in the list and so on.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. Let me read up a bit and make some sense of it now that I have this information and then I will mark this as accepted.